# Display Magento block with non-default theme on external landing page

Tags: magento

I'm working on a static php landing page that is getting accessed outside of Magento and I'm trying to pull a Magento block using with a non-default theme.

I'm able to get the block to show using the default theme, but I'm not sure how I can specify an alternate theme to use.  Both themes are set within the same package.

This is what I have thus far:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles)->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();
$layout->getBlock('topLinks')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do it by "theme" directly.  You would need to use the store code that has the theme in it that you want to use.  For example, if you have a store code of "Main Store" with a Store View of "English" then you would need to set the theme in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes` after changing the Current Configuration Scope.

After doing that, you could then specify the store code in the `Mage::app()` part of your code like this:

```
  $layout = $Mage::app('YOUR_STORE_CODE')->getLayout();
```

Your code errors out for me as it is.  You'll need to specify `$handles` or set it to `default`.

Here is a pretty good post about it that may help:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/262102/#t352798